# Need help with proper terms for a fantasy character's clothing/armor

Tags: characters, fantasy, description

Can someone please tell me what the white garment underneath his armor would be called in this picture? I'm trying to refer to a piece like it in my story, but I don't know the proper term for it. I'm guessing a tunic or a tabard?

[image]

PS sorry if this is the wrong place to ask. I wasn't sure where to put it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how historic you should be with fantasy armor. The proper name for that white garnment is **surcoat**.

It's too long to be a tabard and he's wearing it *over* his chainmail (so not a tunic, that went *under*) to protect it from the wind and the sun as for example the famous surcoats worn by Templar Knights.

But the plates he's wearing over the surcoat only make sense because it's fantasy armor. I think he looks a little like Altaïr from the Assassin's Creed games. In the games, the white garnment that goes over the armor and it's still covered sometimes by plates of armor is called *robe* and *hooded robe*. It isn't the best historical name, but it's intended to be pictured easily by a large population.

So I'd call it a hooded robe worn over the armor but tightened to the body with belts and flexible plates.

EDIT: After looking at "cosplay guides" for Altaïr, most of them go for hooded robes or hooded vest and none for surcoat.

Comment: Thank you so much! That’s really helpful. I’ll go with hooded robe. And thanks for the ideas also on how to describe it in the context of the armor. This is one of my weak areas, so that’s also very helpful! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really make it out from the picture, but the thing that one *should* wear under armour is a [gambeson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambeson).